# Strategy for transparent Android app that allows 3rd party app behind it to update

Tags: java, android, android-activity, transparency

I have an Android app that is transparent that monitors for an event and then displays a message and toggles the background between transparent and a translucent red. The app itself is working exactly as I was hoping. The problem is that only the top most app (my app) is active and updating the view. The app displays over a 3rd party app that runs a live video stream. I want the live video stream app to continue to update while my transparent app is on top. Since I have no control over the other app and it doesn't support multi-window approach, I am looking for a different approach or work around to accomplish the same thing.

I have read of people trying to use a system popup based on a service. Does anyone have experience trying to solve a similar problem and found a good approach for designing the app or a work around?

Answer (score 1):

Try to google about **Activity lifecycle**. When another app comes as the top application (let's say your transparent app) the last playing application goes to **onPause** until the user bring the last app back to the top again. 
The short answer is: what you want is not possible.
any question?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am very familiar with the life cycle of apps in Android. That is why I am looking for a different approach or workaround to accomplish a similar capability. I don't want to try force my transparent app solution to do something Android will not allow. I want to keep a similar capability, namely to have the live stream continue to work but be able to overlay a notification on top based on a detected event. The notification needs to include a button for acknowledging the event.